# Openstack: Error on Puppet while installing on redhat 6.4

Tags: linux, puppet, openstack, rhel

I am installing the Openstack with following steps:

1. Installed openstack kernel
2. yum -y update ( Doesn't update anything)
3. setup the ntp
4. reboot
5. installed openstack-packstack
6. Generate answer file
7. openstack --answer-file=/root/answerfile.txt

and an error occurs in puppet configuration:

```
Adding Horizon manifest entries...                     [ DONE ]
Preparing servers...                                   [ DONE ]
Adding post install manifest entries...                [ DONE ]
Installing Dependencies...                             [ DONE ]
Copying Puppet modules and manifests...                [ DONE ]
Applying Puppet manifests...
Applying 192.168.170.143_prescript.pp
```

**ERROR**

```
ERROR : Error during puppet run : err: /Stage[main]//Package[openstack-selinux]/ensure: change from absent to present failed: Execution of '/usr/bin/yum -d 0 -e 0 -y install openstack-selinux' returned 1: Error: Nothing to do
Please check log file /var/tmp/packstack/20140302-121029-B85D0p/openstack-setup.log for more information.
```

I have already installed the EPEL repo and Local CD repo. And also installed the puppet with 
(yum install puppet) before above installation (I have tried with our steps from manual and book but it doesn't worked).

Any suggestion for this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ERROR : Error during puppet run : err: /Stage[main]//Package[openstack-selinux]/ensure: change from absent to present failed: Execution of '/usr/bin/yum -d 0 -e 0 -y install openstack-selinux' returned 1: Error: Nothing to do
```

This error message says that there is no such package in yum repositories as openstack-selinux. Check your yum repos and find out what repo has to be added.

As far as I see online, you simply need to add OpenStack repo with:

```
yum install http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/x86_64/epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm
```